# Handling Irregular Time Series Data with Multiple Categories in Hourly Resolution Embeddings

Tags: time-series, embedding

I'm working with a time series dataset that has 100 categories for a single feature, and I've generated embeddings for these categories. However, my problem arises when I am trying to sample the data to hourly resolution. There are situations where multiple categories fall within the same hour. How should I appropriately handle the embeddings in this scenario?

I'd appreciate any guidance or insights on the best practices for handling such irregular time series data with embeddings. Thank you!